# Issue computing product with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I was wondering if someone could help me understand why my code is not executing the sum of the user input variable and the line of code that converts centimeters to inches and reads the result to an input box. See code:

```
<select id="option">
    <option value="option1">Select</option>
    <option value="option2">Centimeters/Inches</option>
</select>

Input Value:
    <ul class="input-list style-2 clearfix">
        <li>
         <input type="text" placeholder=":input" id="value">
         </li>
    </ul>

<button onclick="calcFunction()" class="myButton">Convert</button>

Result:
<ul class="input-list style-2 clearfix">
    <li>
    <input type="text" id="resultbox1">
     </li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align:center">
Equals
</p>
<ul class="input-list style-2 clearfix">
    <li>
     <input type="text" id="resultbox2">
     </li>
 </ul>
```

And my Javascript

```
<script>
var op1 = document.getElementById("option");
var value = document.getElementById('value').value;
var centimetersinches;

function calcFunction() {

        if (op1.options[op1.selectedIndex].value == 'option1') {
            document.getElementById('resultbox1').value = 'Select a value';
            document.getElementById('resultbox2').value = 'Select a value';

        } else if (op1.options[op1.selectedIndex].value == 'option2') {
            centimetersinches = value * .394;
            document.getElementById('resultbox1').value = value + ' centimeters';
            document.getElementById('resultbox2').value = centimetersinches + ' inches';


        }
```

I do have a bit of jquery before the calcFunction function, but I do not think that would have anything to do with it. From what I understand, this should work. The strings after the variables for the result boxes are displayed in the result boxes, but I cannot get the variable centimetersinches to display. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try moving your var declarations inside your function. They are executing when the page renders, then not updated when you are executing your function (best guess w/o full source).

Comment: haha! genius. Looks like I was declaring them at the top of the script and you were right (also, I was using the same variable in some code right before the calc function. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JSfiddle and fixed it there -

http://jsfiddle.net/ajsrypf3/2/

2 things

1. You were missing a closing paranthesis for the function
2. You need to read the input fields every time a click event occurs. That means that following three lines should be inside your calcFunction

   var op1 = document.getElementById("option");

   var value = document.getElementById('value').value;

   var centimetersinches;

Fixed code is here

```
calcFunction = function () {

    var op1 = document.getElementById("option");
    var value = document.getElementById('value').value;
    var centimetersinches; 

        if (op1.options[op1.selectedIndex].value == 'option1') {
            document.getElementById('resultbox1').value = 'Select a value';
            document.getElementById('resultbox2').value = 'Select a value';

        } else if (op1.options[op1.selectedIndex].value == 'option2') {
            centimetersinches = value * .394;
            document.getElementById('resultbox1').value = value + ' centimeters';
            document.getElementById('resultbox2').value = centimetersinches + ' inches';


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"try moving your var declarations inside your function. They are executing when the page renders, then not updated when you are executing your function (best guess w/o full source)" -pherris